# How to prevent cmake adding "compatibility_version" for gcc?

Tags: android, gcc, cmake

I'm pretty new to cmake and i'm trying to cross-compile libftdi for ARM Linux (Android).

Why cmake adds "-compatibility_version" to gcc command-line which leads to error:

```
/softdev/arm-toolchain/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc  -O2 -g -DNDEBUG -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names  -L/softdev/arm-libs/lib -compatibility_version 2.0.0 -current_version 2.0.0 -o libftdi1.2.0.0.dylib -install_name /Users/asmirnov/Documents/dev/src/libftdi-1.0/src/libftdi1.2.dylib CMakeFiles/ftdi1.dir/ftdi.c.o CMakeFiles/ftdi1.dir/ftdi_stream.c.o /usr/local/lib/libusb-1.0.dylib 
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: error: 2.0.0: No such file or directory
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: error: 2.0.0: No such file or directory
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: error: /Users/asmirnov/Documents/dev/src/libftdi-1.0/src/libftdi1.2.dylib: No such file or directory
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: error: unrecognized option '-compatibility_version'
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: error: unrecognized option '-current_version'
make[2]: *** [src/libftdi1.2.0.0.dylib] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/ftdi1.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Since i can't find "compatibility_version" command-line parameter in supported by gcc [parameters list](http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/comopts.html) is it cmake error or cmake configuration problem?

**UPDATE: problem #1 solved (hacked)**

i've solved the problem by commenting the next lines in ../Modules/Platforms/Darwin.cmake:

```
# 4ntoine (fix for libftdi compilation using cmake)
#set(CMAKE_C_OSX_COMPATIBILITY_VERSION_FLAG "-compatibility_version ")
#set(CMAKE_C_OSX_CURRENT_VERSION_FLAG "-current_version ")
#set(CMAKE_CXX_OSX_COMPATIBILITY_VERSION_FLAG "${CMAKE_C_OSX_COMPATIBILITY_VERSION_FLAG}")
#set(CMAKE_CXX_OSX_CURRENT_VERSION_FLAG "${CMAKE_C_OSX_CURRENT_VERSION_FLAG}")

# ...

# 4ntoine (fix for libftdi build using cmake)
#if(NOT XCODE)
# Enable shared library versioning.  This flag is not actually referenced
# but the fact that the setting exists will cause the generators to support
# soname computation.
#  set(CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_SONAME_C_FLAG "-install_name")
#endif()
```

I know it's not good especially when you are not sure what you're doing ;)

Now i have another **problem #2**:

```
cd /Users/asmirnov/Documents/dev/src/libftdi-1.0/build/src && /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.11.1/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/ftdi1.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/softdev/arm-toolchain/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc  -O2 -g -DNDEBUG -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names  -L/softdev/arm-libs/lib -o libftdi1.dylib   CMakeFiles/ftdi1.dir/ftdi.c.o CMakeFiles/ftdi1.dir/ftdi_stream.c.o /softdev/arm-libs/lib/libusb-1.0.so 
/softdev/arm-toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: /softdev/arm-toolchain/bin/../sysroot/usr/lib/crtbegin_dynamic.o: in function _start:crtbrand.c(.text+0x78): error: undefined reference to 'main'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [src/libftdi1.dylib] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/ftdi1.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Where is your makefile?:)

Comment: "Makefile" is in project root directory

Comment: I mean, post it please.

Comment: i've cleared out that cmake expects clang to be compiler and "compatibility_version" is recognized by clang, but not by gcc. So the question is how to make cmake generate command-line for gcc and not for clang? Just redefine -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER and -DCMAKE_CPP_COMPILER does not help

Comment: I am by no means an expert on cmake, but try overriding `COMPILER_FLAGS`